# Error in white.drawn - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

The code shown below is to work out the hypergeometric distribution for the different gene lists. However, an error comes up stating that there is a non-numeric argument to the binary operator. Any ideas what needs to be altered?

```
   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Hypergeometric p values
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Set up empty matrix
    # ....

    hypergeo <- function(white.drawn, white, black, drawn, do.log=FALSE) {
      # Info: http://digitheadslabnotebook.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-r-for-introductory-statistics_21.html
      # dhyper(q, m, n, k, log = FALSE)
      #        q = number of successes; "white balls drawn" (here: number of genes that overlap)
      #        m + n = N ; N = total number of genes
      #        m = "white balls in urn"; total number of TF-bound genes
      #        n = "black balls in urn"; total number of genes NOT bound by the TF
      #        k = "number of balls drawn from urn"; sample size
      if (white < 1) {return(NA)}
      p <- phyper(white.drawn-1, white, black, drawn, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p=do.log)
      return(p)
    } # end: hypergeo

    y <- rep(NA, x)
    mx.p <- matrix(y, ncol=length(gene.lists))
    mx.p

    row.names(mx.p) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
    colnames(mx.p) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
    mx.p



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # loop to work our hypergeometric distribution
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
      g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
      for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
        g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
        a <- intersect(g1,g2)
        b <- length(a)
        balls.white <- length(g1)
        balls.black <- 31253 - length(g1)
        balls.white.drawn <- length(intersect(g1,g2))
        balls.drawn <- length (g2)
        balls.total <- 31253
        p <- hypergeo(white.drawn = balls.white.drawn,
                      white = balls.white,
                      black = balls.black,
                      drawn =balls.drawn, do.log = FALSE)

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you define `balls.white.drawn <- intersect(g1, g2)`. The intersection of those two sets will typically not be a single number, it will be a vector (a vector of genes in your case). My sense is that you want the *number* of elements in the intersection of g1 and g2, so you want `balls.white.drawn <- length(intersect(g1, g2))`, although that's already what you've defined a to be.

Comment: Hi, another question has come up - why is this code giving me a value when comparing MTB down-regulated genes (discovery) with the same gene list. It should be zero whenever two identical gene lists are being compared because there would obviously be no overlap in that case. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think I understand. If the lists are identical, shouldn't there be perfect overlap?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what should happen. There should be a perfect overlap and hence a value of 0 when doing the hypergeometric test. For all the remaining identical gene lists, when compared, I got 0 as the p-value from the hypergeometric test which is what i expected.

Comment: Is there a place I could find these gene lists to do debugging?

Comment: Could you possibly provide me with your email and i could forward my script over. Would that be helpful? Otherwise, which method which you recommend for sharing them with you?

Comment: The script is clear, but would you be able to send the actual files? You could send them to joseph.c.mcintyre@gmail.com

Comment: Hi joseph, have you managed to look at the files at all? not sure if you have received my email

Comment: Sorry, I haven't yet. Will try to get a chance today.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: Is the script you're using the same as the one currently posted? And you want to check the value which is returned when you compare the MTB down-regulated list to itself?

Comment: Yes, i edited the script to reflect the latest one i am currently working on. And that is correct indeed.

Comment: Hey, I would like to round all of my values in my mx.p matrix to 1d.p. I have tried using mx.p[j,i] <- round(mx.p, digits = 1) but this returns N/A instead of my values. Do you know which function would work here?

Comment: If you have a matrix, you should be able to just run `round(mx.p, digits = 1)`; maybe store `mx.p_rounded <- round(mx.p, digits = 1)`.

Comment: I just tried that - an error message came up stating: 'non-numeric argument to mathematical function'

Comment: That means that one of the columns of mx.p is non-numeric. You need to select only the numeric columns (e.g., `mx.p[, c('var1', 'var2')]`)

Comment: That is rather unusual, all of my values in mx.p are numerical. Only the row names and column names are characters.

Comment: Are they stored as columns? Row and column names shouldn't get passed to the round function. Try running str(mx.p) and post the result.

Comment: chr [1:8, 1:8] "0" "6.471e-292" "0.9754" "1" "1.072e-251" "1.391e-138" "0.915" "1" "6.471e-292" "0" "1" "1" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:8] "GSE108363_BCGdown_V" "GSE108363_BCGdown_D" "GSE108363_BCGup_V" "GSE108363_BCGup_D" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:8] "GSE108363_BCGdown_V" "GSE108363_BCGdown_D" "GSE108363_BCGup_V" "GSE108363_BCGup_D" ...

Comment: So that's a matrix of strings, not numbers. Try `round(as.numeric(mx.p), digits = 1)`

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I appreciate your time in helping me out. Apologies for the mistake, I tried your new suggestion but the values haven't changed at all.

Comment: When you run `round(as.numeric(mx.p), digits = 1)`, do you get the matrix with the rounded values? If so, you can run `mx.p <- round(as.numeric(mx.p), digits = 1)`.

Comment: I guess since I am dealing with such small numbers, all of them once rounded, are coming out as 0.0, 1.0 or 0.9. What I am trying to achieve is e.g. a value of 6.471e-292 to be written as 6.5e-292.

Comment: Oh, okay, rounding won't help that. You want the `signif()` function, which can round to a certain number of significant digits, as in `signif(6.471e-292, 2)`.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it possible to integrate this function into my loop so that all the values automatically round to 2sf?

Comment: Probably. Just return `signif(p_val, 2)` instead of `pval`

Comment: 'non-numeric argument to mathematical function' - this came up again. Any ideas about using formatC() I am working on the same script - wondering whether you could access it again to see where the issue lies? Apologies for any inconvenience this has caused.

Comment: Where is the error coming up? I don't see where it would return characters; right now everything looks numeric. If you can tell me what command produces the error, I might be able to say more.

Comment: Error in signif(mx.p, digits = 2) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function - it comes up after running the function